# How to move two servos at the same time using pyfirmata, python and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, servo

I am trying to program a robot arm and I need two servos to run at the same time and be able to run in different directions for example on going 90° to 180° and the other servo going 90° to 0° , I am using a Arduino, python and pyfirmata any help would be good thank you!

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201')

armlower2 = board.get_pin('d:6:s')
armlower1 = board.get_pin('d:10:s')

for angle in range(90, 180, 1):
    armlower2.write(angle)
    time.sleep(0.015)

for angle in range(180, 90, -1):
    armlower2.write(angle)
    time.sleep(0.015)

for angle in range(90, 0, -1):
    armlower1.write(angle)
    time.sleep(0.015)

for angle in range(0, 90, 1):
    armlower1.write(angle)
    time.sleep(0.015)
```

This moves the servos but only one at a time ?

Comment: put everything in separate functions and use something like [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: I am new to python, I will look in to threading could you help with a example? thank you

Comment: Yes - check out my answer, though I haven't really used much threading.

Comment: thank you I will give it a go tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), here's a really simple example:

```py
import threading

def move_armlower2(): 
    for angle in range(90, 180, 1):
        armlower2.write(angle)
        time.sleep(0.015)

    for angle in range(180, 90, -1):
        armlower2.write(angle)
        time.sleep(0.015)

def move_armlower1():
    for angle in range(90, 0, -1):
        armlower1.write(angle)
        time.sleep(0.015)

   for angle in range(0, 90, 1):
        armlower1.write(angle)
        time.sleep(0.015)

threads = [
    threading.Thread(target=move_armlower2), # Creating threads
    threading.Thread(target=move_armlower1) 
]

for th in threads:
    th.start() # Starts the thread

for th in threads:
    th.join() # Waits for the thread to terminate
```

#### References:

- [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)
- [`Thread.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start)
- [`Thread.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

Comment: thank you I will give it a go tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You should write your main loop around the concepts of "current value" and "want value", i.e., the values you want vs the values (angles) you currently are at. This can be expanded to any number of motors using arrays for the motors, and traversing their values in a loop.  But for two, you can simply do the following.

```
// The angle values you want to achieve, and what they currently are
GLOBAL want1, want2
GLOBAL current1, current2
LOOP {
    LOCAL updelta = 1
    LOCAL downdelta = -1
    if want1 > current1
        movearm1(updelta)
        current1 = current1 + updelta
    else if want1 < current1
        movearm1(downdelta)
        current1 = current1 + downdelta
    if want2 > current2
        movearm2(updelta)
        current2 = current2 + updelta
    else if want2 < current2
        movearm2(downdelta)
        current2 = current2 + downdelta

    sleep(0.015)
}
```

Comment: thank you I will give it a go tomorrow and let you know